# Perl - Receive JSON and render on template

Tags: json, perl, mojolicious

I'm trying to expand some app, but I never used Perl before. This uses de framework Mojolicious. 
For now I was able to write this, but I can't find out how to check if it's correct or not.

```
    use JSON::XS;
    use JSON qw( decode_json );
    my $self = shift; 
    my $req = HTTP::Request->new("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments");

    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
            keep_alive => 1,
            timeout => 3000,
            ssl_opts => {
                verify_hostname => 0,
                SSL_verify_mode => IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_VERIFY_NONE
            },
        );
    my $response = $ua->request($req);
    my $body = $response->decoded_content();

$self->stash(
        'body' => $body
        );

    $self->render('view_');
    return;
```

On template I try something like this: (Found somewhere example)

```
<% foreach my $element (@{$body->{"element"}}) { %>
    <p><%= $element->[1]->{"id"} %></p>
<% } %>
```

But got the error:

```
Can't use string ("[ { "postId": 1, "id":"...) as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at template view_.html.ep line 228.
```

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough information here to help. For starters - `$tempHash` is probably not a hash. It's a reference to an array.

Comment: hi @Sobrique What information do you need more ? Thanks

Comment: Where does `$comments` come from? There's a gap between the two blocks of code that mean you definitely don't have a [mcve] for people to look at

Comment: Hi @ChrisTurner $comments doesn't exist. Is some kind of var (array?) with the json data that I want to send to the template. This is the code I was able to write, I have no idea if it's correct or not. Thanks

Comment: If you're using variables that don't exist, the code can't be correct...as well as a [mcve], providing examples of the json input would also help too

Comment: I added that variable after: "The expected result would allow me to send the data (array?) to the template, in order to create a table." the code I have is on the first part.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @melpomene the question is: How I can I received the JSON, parse it to Perl array, and send the array to template

Comment: Isn't that what your code does? If not, what does your code do?

Comment: good question @melpomene ! I have no idea. I started to work around on this today. I even have problems to debug what I have

Comment: Well, which part are you having problems with? Receiving data over HTTP, decoding JSON, or what? Please ask a single, well-defined question.

Comment: @melpomene Changes added to post

Comment: That's not a [mcve].

Comment: Why are you loading both `JSON::XS` and `JSON` but using neither?

Comment: At the beggining I was using JSON. JSON::XS was already on the app

Comment: Have you ever written a program before?

Comment: @melpomene jsut python. never Perl

Comment: @user1234, Welcome to Perl.  If you're doing more Perl it's worth your time to visit https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/perl/ and also spend some time looking at https://perldoc.perl.org  StackOverflow is a wonderful resource.  Perlmonks is also a great community for help with code review, solutions to problems and general coding advice:  http://www.perlmonks.org

Comment: Thanks @daotoad ! fortunately is just this task I have to do with Perl

Answer (score 1):

Your error looks pretty clear:

> Can't use string ("[ { "postId": 1, "id":"...) as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at template view_.html.ep line 228.

It's referring to this line in your template:

```
<% foreach my $element (@{$body->{"element"}}) { %>
```

In this code you're taking the variable `$body` and expecting it to contain a hash reference (because you're using the `->{...}` operator on it). But, as the error says, it doesn't contain a hash reference, it contains a string.

So the problem is that you have a JSON string, where you expect a Perl reference. And that means that you haven't JSON-decoded your JSON string.

Perhaps you think that `$response->decoded_content();` does the JSON decoding. But it doesn't. That does a higher level of decoding. As the [documentation for HTTP::Response says](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response):

> **$r->decoded_content( %options )**
>
> This will return the content after any Content-Encoding and charsets have been decoded. See HTTP::Message for details.

Nothing in there about JSON decoding.

And that's why you're loading (two!) JSON modules. You need to use one of them to decode the JSON to a Perl data structure. Something like this, perhaps:

```
my $body = decode_json( $response->decoded_content() );
```

[**Note:** In a comment, melpomene correctly points out a problem with this. The correct code is:

```
my $body = decode_json( $response->content() );
```

i.e. You shouldn't decode the response body before sending it into `decode_json()`.]

That will, at least, get you a reference into `$body`. I see another problem though. Your JSON string starts with `[`, so it will decode into an array reference, not a hash reference. You'll need to deal with that change. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about your data or what you're trying to do to suggest a solution to that problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This api was just an example. Actually my API starts with : { "data": [{..}, {...}] } so I hope I will not have a problem

Comment: Note that `decode_json($r->decoded_content)` is not quite right because `decoded_content` returns a unicode text string, but `decode_json` takes a byte string (in UTF-8 format).

Comment: thanks @DaveCross and  melpomene. About my foreach, could please tell me if i'm going in a good way? Thanks for you time to explain me this. Perl is really complicated, when you don't know anything, and you have to do some task fast.